# How to check if more than one instance of React (or any other library) is loaded?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

Working with Webpack Module Federation, i'm wondering if there's a way to check how many instances of a particular library (such as `React`, `react-query`, etc..) are loaded in my application?